# Need to display 'Name' instaed of Id SOQL

Tags: soql

EDIT:

```
public List<SelectOption> getopenPresentationOptions()
{
     List<AssetEntry__c> make_model_list = [SELECT id, name, Make__r.Name, Model__r.Name FROM AssetEntry__c];

     system.debug('make_model_list   ' + make_model_list );       
}
```

When I ran this query in developer console it does retrieve the `Name` but the same query when I have that in Apex code it returns the `Id` I have confirmed through using `system.debug`

```
SELECT id, name, Make__r.Name, Model__r.Name FROM AssetEntry__c
```

Why is that behavior, am I missing something?

Comment: Weird !! It should return the name in apex code as well.. You mean Class when You apex.. correct ??

Comment: yes i mean its class..., I double check again its doing the same

Comment: What are you doing with this query in your apex code? Can you please share the piece of code where you're trying to retrieve the Name?

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you debug the list it will only show the reference to the related record

You will need to debug the individual Model__r.Name from each record to get the names, or store them in a collection or something

or

```
List<AssetEntry__c> make_model_list = [SELECT id, name, Make__r.Name FROM AssetEntry__c];

     for(AssetEntry__c rec : make_model_list){
        Model__c mod = (Model__c)rec.getSobject('Make__r');
        system.debug('make_model   ' + mod.Name );
     }
```

Example from a working verified code

```
Milestone1_Milestone__c audit = [Select Account__c, Account__r.Name, ID From Milestone1_Milestone__c limit 1];
Account a = (Account)audit.getSobject('Account__r');
system.debug(logginglevel.error,a.Name);
```

Comment: getting this error `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object `

Comment: its throwing me error on `system.debug('make_model   ' + mod.Name );` but when I look at the system.debug this is what I see `21:40:14.136 (136432197)|USER_DEBUG|[13]|DEBUG|make_model  ` Model__c:{Name=Toyota, Id=a0Tj0000002Mg3wEAC}``

Comment: @AbuHamzah - then it is not throwing an error on that line....

Comment: yes it is if I just have `system.debug('make_model ' + mod)` then no error only when I try to access Name like mod.Name

Comment: Try renaming the property to something other than mod, say myModel or something. Otherwise it should work just fine unless there is a clash with the name

Comment: I do not even have any other code besides this few lines which I have posted so I can not even suspect that its coming from some where else so I'm 200% sure and as soon I remove the field name from the object it works fine without any error.

Comment: sadly same error even after rename system.debug('make_model   ' + mymodel.Name);

Comment: I had Model__r.Name in the soql twice, remove the duplicate

Comment: I found the cause so I have some null data and that's why it was throwing me that error so I end-up adding a condition, thanks for your help 1+

Comment: Great, glad we could get there